# Sass import doesn't work after using gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: sass, gulp

I was using gulp-sass to compile SCSS fine for my project. Then I decided to switch to .sass for its simplicity. I switched to gulp-ruby-sass, but then the import doesn't work. Here is what I have:

```
@import bootstrap/mixins
```

My directory structure:

```
|-- app
|   |-- app.js
|   |-- app.scss
|   |-- app_controller.js
|   |-- app_controller_test.js 
|   |-- bootstrap
|   |   |-- _mixins.scss
|   |   |-- _normalize.scss
|   |   |-- _variables.scss
```

In my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('css', function(){
gulp.src(['app.scss','./app/**/*.sass'])
    .pipe(plugins.rubySass())
    .pipe(plugins.concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

Then I got this error:

```
error ./main/main.sass (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/mixins.
Load paths:
/private/var/folders/kn/29d686ds16s31t8mp0957dt40000gn/T/gulp-ruby-sass
```

Please help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: @Aperçu i just edited. error posted

Comment: You only want the mixins ? Have you try a `@import 'bootstrap';` ?

Answer (score 0):

Should it be `gulp.src(['app.scss','./app/**/*.scss'])` instead of `gulp.src(['app.scss','./app/**/*.sass'])`?

Comment: Don't think the extension is really a problem

Comment: @sarbbottam No, all my files are in *.sass format except app.scss.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a load path:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src(['app.scss','./app/**/*.sass'])
    .pipe(plugins.rubySass({
      loadPath: [
        process.cwd() + '/app'
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

You can add multiple load paths by comma seperating them. The function `process.cwd()` is used to get the path to your `gulpfile.js`